# .htaccess Consistent "Request Exceeded The Limit Of 10 Internal Redirects..." (Code Included)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm having some very strange issues.

I'm running my application on AWS Elastic Beanstalk, my .htaccess file is at the root of the accessible web level of my application.

I'm constantly seeing issues in my error log, it seems with every request I'm getting the "Request Exceeded The Limit Of 10 Internal Redirects" message. Although, pages are loading and working fine, the fact these errors are throwing and my load on the server is far higher than it should be is indicating to me there's a problem somewhere.

I'm not extremely familiar with .htaccess files as I haven't written them for 2 years or so now, and this one is for an old MVC framework I built (though never had problems with until now)

Any help would be appreciated, I'm not sure where to look at this point.

.htaccess file:

```
# -*- mode: apache -*-

AddDefaultCharset utf-8

<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript image/jpg image/jpeg image/png image/gif video/mp4
</ifmodule>

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^\.]+\.[^\.]+$
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteRule ^(\d+\/)?assets/(.*)$ assets/$2 [L]
RewriteRule .*$ app/index.php [L]
```

Comment: Enable the RewriteLog. You're also redirecting `assets/*` to `assets/*` when `(\d+\/)?` is optional.

Comment: Ahh, right. Will do so and check it, if I can't figure it out I'll post the dump.

Comment: Still getting issues, enabling the log seems to be throwing 500 errors..

Answer (score 0):

Have your rules as this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^\d+/(assets/.*)$ $1 [L,NC]

# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^ app/index.php [L]
```

Keep `assets` rule before skip files/directories rule and don't make `\d+/` part optional.